# FastAPI/SQLModel Database listener for websockets

Tags: websocket, sqlalchemy, fastapi, google-cloud-run, sqlmodel

I'm working on a FastAPI/SQLModel based service which uses SQLModel websockets to give users "live" data from a Postgres DB (low latency is fairly key to this application). At the moment the only way I can detect changes to a specific table (or items in a table) is to poll at a given frequency, but I want to try and avoid the overhead of doing this where possible. Are there any well established design patterns for how to listen to updates and get changes with low latency?

I've explored the following options, but haven't yet got a good solution:

- SQLAlchemy events - adding an event listener within the websocket, such as`event.listen(Object, "after_update", update_action)`, but given a websocket response is async and the `update_action` callback isnt this created some problems. In addition to this, the service runs in a container (or multiple when high traffic/load) and it doesn't seem to extend well as a multi-container solution
- Some kind of Notify/Subscribe system - on an update to a table I could notify, and the subscriber in the websocket could pick this up and send through the updated changes to the end user. This *should* work with multiple containers but feels quite heavy handed and means adding notify sections all over my codebase.
- Polling - as explained above its what I have running at the moment, but I don't like the overhead, and it feels like there should be a better "async" way to go about this.

It feels like quite a common problem to face so I'd be interested to know what the best solutions/design patterns are!

Some other notes:

event.listen seemed to have issues when the database was updated by a different user/a different service, as it never triggered.

I had a try at using Redis for the notify/subscribe method but didn't like the idea of adding notifiers all over the codebase. Perhaps some combination of the notify/subscribe system whilst using event listeners to kick off the notify part of the process?